# php -S localhost Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: php

стоит версия php56 mac os, ставил через brew, при запуске php -S localhost:8000 заводится сервер, читает index.html, но как только доходит дело до чтения кода php сервер падает с ответом Segmentation fault: 11

Переключаюсь на версию php71 все работает, подскажите в чем может быть дело?

Comment: а стоит ли разбираться почему не работает 5.6 ? Пишите под 7.1, если с ним проблем нет.

Comment: вопрос в том что вы и как настроили, но как минимум пользоваться 5.6 в настоящее время при разработке новых проектов нерентабельно